# How can I change chrome unstable to chrome beta

Tags: google-chrome

I installed chrome unstable from the chrome site. It was .deb package but because it has problems with some sites, I want to change to chrome beta. I want to change because the previous version of unstable, which is now the beta version worked correctly with no problem.

So how can I remove unstable and install beta since every time I try to install it it gives an error.

Comment: What error? Please include in your question the commands you ran and the errors you got.

Comment: software center said it could not install the beta version because there was an already existing chrome. My first thought was the unstable chrome since it is the only one there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With .deb package you have got new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with google chrome repo description. So now it's possible to install and remove chrome as any regular package:

```
sudo aptitude purge google-chrome-unstable
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install google-chrome-beta
```

Comment: Could you please clarify whether the code you've provided really works?

Comment: thank you it works. i have to install aptitude first but i am sure it works with apt get also.

Comment: works with `apt-get`